Postgres SQL: How to get a kind of rolling correlation?
Given the following structure of data:



X
Y




1
10


1
15


1
12


2
32


2
11


2
45


2
55


3
23


3
34


3
56


3
23


3
45


4
32


4
84


4
24


4
23



I like to correlate X with Y. Taking into account the entire data, this is trivial, of course:
SELECT CORR(X,Y) FROM some_table;

But I like to correlate X with Y in a rolling form. So the result may look like this:



X
CORR(X,Y)




1
0.40


2
0.43



For row X=1, CORR(X,Y) reflects the correlation of X with Y but only for X being 1,2 or 3
Accordingly, for row X=2, the correlation is only for X being 2,3 or 4.
But to be honest, I have no clue how to cover this. First, I thought of using a kind of combination of GROUP BY, LAG and PARTITION, but quite clueless how to combine them in a senseful manner.

Using a window function with order by x range between current row and 2 following (which will find the correlation between all rows with x = current value and current value + 2):
select distinct
    x,
    corr
from (
    select
        x,
        corr(x, y) over (order by x range between current row and 2 following)
    from
        items) items
order by
    x;

Setup:
create table items (x integer not null, y integer not null);

insert into items(x, y) values
    (1, 10),
    (1, 15),
    (1, 12),
    (2, 32),
    (2, 11),
    (2, 45),
    (2, 55),
    (3, 23),
    (3, 34),
    (3, 56),
    (3, 23),
    (3, 45),
    (4, 32),
    (4, 84),
    (4, 24),
    (4, 23);

Output:
x   corr
1   0.5369994889254458
2   0.10527796470131953
3   0.11612585264679108
4   null

Verified with:
select corr(x, y) from (select * from items where x in (1, 2, 3)) items;
# => 0.5369994889254458

select corr(x, y) from (select * from items where x in (2, 3, 4)) items;
# => 0.10527796470131953


To show null for rows where the range of x is not 3:
select distinct
    x,
    case when range = 3 then corr else null end
from (
    select
        x,
        corr(x, y) over w,
        max(x) over w - min(x) over w + 1 as range
    from items
    window w as (order by x range between current row and 2 following)
    ) items
order by
    x;

Output:
1   0.5369994889254458
2   0.10527796470131953
3   null
4   null


Awesome, thx so much. Just one add question: Although there are only 2 distinct X values for the last correlation (seen in row with X=3), the correlation is calculated. Could I modify the query so it shows null for X=3?

Edited my answer to include that.
